# How to keep the properties of an objects in the same order like given object in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am new to client side application development. I got one requirement , is it possible or not , i don't know.Below is my requirement,
I have 3 java script Object like below

```
var obj1={
  'name':'Sachin',
  'age':40,
  'add':'Mumbai'
}

var obj2={
  'age':22,
  'name':'Virat',
  'add':'NewDelhi'
}

var obj3={
  'add':'WI'
  'age':39,
  'name':'Lara'
}
```

They change the order of one object properties , then remaining object properties also should be in the same order.For example they change the Object one order then remaining two object properties also in the same order like object one. Then the output like below.

```
var obj1={
  'name':'Sachin',
  'age':40,
  'add':'Mumbai'
}

var obj2={
  'name':'Virat',
  'age':22,
  'add':'NewDelhi'
}

var obj3={
  'name':'Lara',
  'age':39,
  'add':'WI'
}
```

we are using this in performing sorting, If i am using loops then it takes some time. So that any solution with underscore JS or angular or some other.

Please help me to go forward.

thanks in advance,
Srinivasa Rao.ch

Comment: You cannot sort the properties of an object, nor can you rely on their current order always being the same. If you want this behaviour you would need an array. I don't see the issue though as you surely access the properties of the object by name, so the ordering should be irrelevant.

Comment: Javascript objects are not array, thus they are not ordered. You cannot sort them, as they have no order to sort to begin with. This is different then sorting THROUGH them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't sort the object directly and We don't have any direct methods in underscore Please follow the steps will achieve this.

[Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishnamannem/pmaojgy9/)

```
var obj1 = {
  'name': 'Sachin',
  'age': 40,
  'add': 'Mumbai'
}

var obj2 = {
  'age': 22,
  'name': 'Virat',
  'add': 'NewDelhi'
}


var newObj2 = objSort(obj1, obj2); //arg1 is referal arg2 is need to chang object 

function objSort(obj1, obj2) {
  var obj = {};
  _.each(obj1, function(val, key) {
    obj[key] = obj2[key];
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(newObj2);
```

output is

```
{
  name: "Virat",
  age: 22,
  add: "NewDelhi"
}
```

I hope this will use for you.

Comment: Thanks @vamsi, it is useful to me